# How can I write "@" (at) in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

If I try to use `altgr+v (@)` in an android emulator's `editText`, I cannot write the "@" sign.

The `altgr` is the 2 finger gesture (zoom) by default.

Any other shortcuts or some solution for this?

Comment: you mean you want to type @ symbol in edit text?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Yes

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but still a valid one, since i suffered from that too recently.

Is not possible to type "@" using a keyboard with a language that requires to use  Option+Q or Option+2 in Mac, or AltGr+Q in windows, the emulator does not accept the use of Option nor AltGr keys

the solution is to change the language of keyboard to english ABC so the @ is accesible with Shift+2, in other languages, the number 2 has (") but in english ABC the number 2 has the (@) when you use shift.[image]

Go to settings and change the configuration of your keyboard, in Mac you can just click in the keyboard icon showed in the top bar

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it can be seen and pointed out in below screen [image]

Take your mouse and click at the pointed area you will find new keyboard option and done

You can use your hardware keyboard that is attached with your computer or laptop. To use your hardware keyboard follow below steps

1. Open AVD manager
2. Go to edit option of your desire virtual device
3. Select Show Advance setting button
4. At the bottom you will find enable keyboard option mark that option check

Answer (score 0):

It's still open bug in Google issue tracker from 2017 ‍♂️ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37142228

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this very old question, as it annoyed me as well. I found out that if you run the emulator within Android Studio it works! If it is a separate Window, it does not (at least under Windows).

Settings > Emulator > "Launch in the Running Devices Tool Window" .